# How to execute PowerShell script against all CSV files in a directory?

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I have a script below that I want to execute against all .csv files in a directory. I know I can use Get-ChildItems, but how to filter it for only .csv files in .\ and execute my script?

```
import-csv .\chapters.csv | 
    ConvertTo-Json -Compress | 
    ForEach-Object {$_ -creplace '""NULL""','null'} | 
    Out-File .\chapters.json
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand what you're asking, just use a file glob and pipe the results to **Import-CSV** **. Use a **Foreach-Object** loop to capture the base name of each CSV file to use in naming the output files.

```
Get-ChildItem .\*.csv | Foreach-Object {
  $basename = $_.BaseName
  import-csv $_ | ConvertTo-Json -Compress | Foreach {$_ -creplace '""NULL""','null'} | Out-File ".\$basename.json"
}
```

BTW, there's no "s" at the end of **Get-ChildItem**.

Comment: sorry don't mean to glob them in one file, but how to I execute the script per file? So one json file will be generated for each (chapters.csv, authors.csv, books.csv, etc will generate chapters.json, authors.json, books.json).

Comment: "glob" doesn't mean to collect data into a single file. It's a standard computing term that means to match names (particularly filenames) using wildcards: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_%28programming%29. `Get-ChildItem .\*.csv` will select all files with the **.csv** extension and feed them one by one into the pipeline to be converted to objects by **Import-Csv**. Did you even try it?

Comment: Actually, I just noticed a problem, which is that the output file is always **chapters.json**, and it gets overwritten each time, so you'll only have the results from the last CSV file.  I'll modify the answer so that the **.json** files will have the same base names as the **.csv** files.